# Problema para tratar los datos de una consulta con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, funciones

Obtengo los datos de: `{% evento.data.categorias %}` y quiero tratar esta información con php.

Cuando hago el php `echo "{% evento.data.categorias %}"` se muestra perfectamente el valor, sin embargo no puedo recorrer la cadena que se muestra para comprobar si hay una palabra en concreto dentro de esa cadena.

¿Supongo que sera porque no reconoce que es un string? 
¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer?

Hago lo siguiente:

```
        <?php
            $mystring = "{% evento.data.categorias %}";
            $findme   = 'Promociones';
            $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

            if ($pos === false) {
                    echo "La cadena '$findme' no fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
                } else {
                    echo "La cadena '$findme' fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
                    echo " y existe en la posición $pos";
                }
        ?>
```

Y os aseguro que la palabra Promociones esta dentro de $mystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo porque usas la etiqueta de php en tu código junto a echo, me imaginaba que estabas en una plantilla Blade. Si quieres mantener limpio tu código te recomiendo que leas este artículo y que hagas una directiva de Blade que puedas usar donde desees.

https://styde.net/directivas-personalizadas-con-blade-en-laravel-5-1/

Para que te quede algo como esto

```
@if(!strpos($evento.data.categories,"Promoción"))
   <b>No se encuentra</b>
@else
   <i>Se encontró una coincidencia</i>
@endif
```

Si no quieres hacer una directiva de php puedes usar tu mismo código pero entre estas directivas

```
@php
//Código aquí
@endphp
```